# sql having columnValue > 0 by a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, having

I can't find any solution for this table :

```
DocId | Item| Service              | Qty
1     | 10  | Energie activa       | 9.7140000000
1     | 18  | Tarif distributie JT | 9.7140000000
1     | 19  | Tarif transport TG   | 9.7140000000
1     | 20  | Tarif transport TL   | 9.7140000000
1     | 14  | Serviciu sistem      | 9.7140000000
1     | 15  | Cogenerare           | 9.7140000000
```

I need to select * from table for each DocId, where Item = 15 (this is ok). But, must have another condition, having Qty > 0 where Item is 18, 19 or 20

```
select *
from table
where item = 15
```

and something like :

```
having Qty > 0 where Item = 18 or Item = 19 or Item = 20
```

I don't need something like below code, because I have many inner joins in my entire query and thousands of DocId.

```
select *
from table
where item = 15 and (select qty from table where item = 18 and docId = 1) > 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the docids meeting both conditions using `group by` and `having`:

```
select docid
from table t
group by docid
having sum(case when item = 15 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when item in (18, 19, 20) and qty then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

You can get the original rows using `in`, `exists`, or `join`.

If you want just the row with `item = 15`, you can use `exists` directly:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.item = 15 and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.docid = t.docid and
                    t2.item in (18, 19, 20) and
                    t2.qty > 0
             );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use parentheses to combine conditions...

```
select *
from table
where item = 15 or (item in (18,19,20) and qty>0)
```

Comment: this will select all lines with item = 15 ,16, 17, 18 (and qty> 0 for last 3). I need to select only where item = 15 where qty > 0 for item = 18 for each DocId